# What is the meaning of 送上 here?

Tags: meaning

In this sentence 送上 means what?? I think is means 'send = 送 to attend = 上(a series of lectures) = 一场讲座' but maybe it is just 送给？？

据报道，某石油化工公司前不久举办了一场心理知识讲座，为近百名员工送上了一把找到工作快乐和取得成功的“心灵钥匙“。

Answer (score 5):

送上，送给 both means send.

Two differences：

1.送上 is more polite。

2. in different sentence structure。

a.   为 someone 送上 something。

b.   送给 someone  something。

This sentence equals to ... ... 送给近百名员工一把找到工作快乐和取得成功的“心灵钥匙“。

### reply to the comments.

心灵钥匙 is a description of 讲座，it is a metaphor.
This lecture is the 心灵钥匙。

examle
学校组织了一次军训活动，为广大师生送上了一次军旅体验。

军训活动 is the 军旅体验。

Comment: How do the lectures come into this? The employees first attend the lectures, don't they? '公司为员工举办一场讲座，然后发给员工一把‘灵心钥匙’ 这样的意思？

Comment: @Pedroski  reply in the answers.

Comment: @Pedroski "心灵钥匙" is metaphor. That is to say the lecture acted like a key for the staff to access the success. In other words, the lecture enlightened everyone's soul. Make sense?

Comment: Aha, so the lecture, not the company, gave the staff 'enlightenment'. This part is really a relative clause '...lectures, which .....' 为近百名员工送上了一把找到工作快乐和取得成功的“心灵钥匙“。

Answer (score 3):

**送上**

**[KEY](http://www.cjkware.com/search?query=%E9%80%81%E4%B8%8A&option=)**

> [ v ]
>
> ◊ deliver (to a superior)
>
> ◊ present (to a superior)
>
> ◊ send (wishes, etc.)

so we have:

`送上了一把.......钥匙`

send/deliver/present - a - key

you could, as you suggested, even replace **送上** with **送给** here (meaning wise, not grammatically).

Answer (score 3):

```
送上 - send
```

送上 is usually used in situation where things are delivered humbly / 'with a heart'.  You will use 送上 when sending a gift or a blessing for example.

```
送给 - send to
```

Since it means 'sending to', in most cases it is followed by the person / party receiving the 'thing' being sent.  I.e. It is not practical to use in your example.

Also I believe it is a term in conjunction with `收下`, as a term used by the receiver of the things you have just 送上.